# Upgraded to 14.10 - No longer prompted for Privilege Escalation

Tags: unity, 14.10, policykit

I upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10.  The process was not exactly smooth. I had space errors on /boot so some of the updates failed.  I was finally able to get everything update.

Now though nothing in Unity prompts for privilege escalation.  Mounting files, editing users, creating folders, etc.  I'll get get access denied, and no password prompt.  I spent quite a bit of time googling this and only thing that seemed to make sense is maybe an issue with `polkit`. So I did the answer from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510252/ubuntu-no-longer-prompts-for-root-privilege-but-doesnt-give-it-either):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome
> ```

This did not fix the problem.

Comment: If this is identical to the other question it should be dealt with in that question via comments / answers etc. Duplicate questions should be avoided on AskUbuntu and other SE sites.

Comment: Whats the deal with this site? I get it no duplicate posts, so I comment on original post and its deleted.  Anyone here to help? I've searched this site and google to no end and have not found any solution to why i'm not getting prompted for privilege escalation in Unity.

Comment: Either your problem is the same, in which case you should be able to get an answer through the original post by commenting appropriately, or your problem is different in which case you should update your question to reflect that. I recommend seeing http://askubuntu.com/tour for how this all works. We are a question and answer site, not a discussion forum so things may work differently to what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after the same upgrade. Re-installation of policykit neither worked for me. I was able to solve mine after checked the logs under /var/log/lightdm with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session
```

The root privilege prompt appeared again after reboot.
Please be prepared some other packages might be broken with that, e.g. virt-manager.
Fortunately, reinstalling the broken packages worked this time.