# Mount Flashdrive: Not Authorized to perform operation

Tags: 14.10, usb-drive, privileges

At first this issue seemed to be related solely to usb's.  When I insert a USB i get "Unable to mount xGb volume
Not Authorized to perform operation"

Previously it would prompt for root password to mount. Upon closer examination this appears to be related to the privilege escalation prompt.  Any feature that would normally require a root password doesn't prompt therefore is denied.

As another example under System Settings > User Accounts I can't click the unlock button. Previously it would prompt for root, now I no longer even have the option.

Edit: I know how Sudo works, but why isn't this happening through the GUI? Previously if you plugged in a flash drive it'd prompt for PW then mount automagically. It seems to be an issue with GUI privilege escalation in general not just mounting drives.  Even if I go to Disks and click mount it doesn't mount because it never prompts for PW.

Answer (score 51):

In Ubuntu 18, this error is caused by Chrome Remote Desktop. The solution is:

1. Stop the Chrome Remote Desktop Service:

   ```
   /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --stop
   ```
2. Open all external disks, that logo appears
3. Start again the Chrome remote desktop service:

   ```
   /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start
   ```

I think you have to do this after each reboot.

Comment: That  quite unexpectedly worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: :O It works for me too. Any reason why?

Comment: This worked for me as well. I removed the chrome-remote-desktop for good. Thank you

Comment: to remove remote desktop execute `sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop`

Comment: Awkwardly intelligent!

Comment: wow. this is still happening it seems--i'm on xubuntu 20.04

Comment: Omg, it can't be thi-

Answer (score 6):

You have already opened some application which is holding the mount for lock so you are not able to mount it. The application might be gparted,ubuntu-installer or others.

Comment: I just logged into system.

Comment: May be some startup program or service is mounting it.

Comment: And how is one supposed to know what application is holding the mount for lock?

Comment: you are awesome! I had gparted opened haha

Comment: In my case the problem was Chrome Remote Desktop. Uninstalling it fixed my issue. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in/1196273#1196273.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my fix in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578655/upgraded-to-14-10-no-longer-prompted-for-privilege-escalation) before I saw this one:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session

Please be cautious this might break some other packages. In which case try to reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

I recently has this issue as a result of having installed Chrome Remote Desktop. Other commenters have suggested uninstalling it however I use it often and have trouble using other remote tools due to being on a university network. At any rate, killing all the processes which referred to chrome-remote-desktop worked for me.

Comment: My related answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196248/automount-when-clicking-on-disks-in-gui-file-manager-suddenly-stopped-working-in/1196273#1196273. Also, please update your answer to include the command you used to kill all processes which referred to `chrome-remote-desktop`.

Comment: Side note: my answer above also recommends using NoMachine. You might give it a shot. They are a company attempting to become well-known by letting everyone use it for free, so they have put in a TON of work to make it highly-functional and bug-free, and I am very impressed. The never-ending bugs in Chrome Remote Desktop on Linux are killing me, so I think I'll stick with NoMachine.

Comment: I was not interested in providing a comprehensive tutorial on killing processes. I simply ran 'ps -aux | grep google' and then 'kill -9 <id>' as anyone can learn on stack exchange. I have also successfully used chrome remote desktop regularly interruption-free after fixing an initial issue regarding the desktop session config, which can also be found with a quick search on stack exchange.

Comment: Although this answer did not provide an example on how to solve the issue, indeed this is the reason for my case and a legit answer. I don't see any reason that it got downvoted. Upvoted from negative.

Answer (score 0):

For me the missing bit was **the user not being member of the group `plugdev`**

Terminal way to add myuser to the group:

```
sudo usermod -aG plugdev myuser
```

After this I didn't even have to logout or restart any services.

Answer (score 0):

As a quikly workaround, if you open RemoteDesktop, and stop your computer to be accesible from Remote Acces section (click on the trash icon) then you recover the elevated privileges function.
When you activate it again, the drive remains mounted but the elevation procces fails again

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue with reading the hard disk drives.

The disk was actually /dev/sda8.
I had to create a mount point.

```
sudo cd mkdir /media/mydisk
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /media/mydisk
```

And this worked for me.

To verify it, use

```
cd /media/mydisk 
ls
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the most elegant solution was to remove my computer from https://remotedesktop.google.com/access due to the fact I was not using the remote access and left a dangling node and it looks like Linux was just trying to protect the system with "Not Authorized to perform operation" of new devices? Anyhow this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
# place in 
#create dir if needed
#/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/automount.pkla


[Allow Automount]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow Eject]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow Mounting of fstab]
Identity=unix-group:plugdev
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: It would be better to surround your answer by some explanation.

Comment: While the answer is correct, it misses explanation as @zx485 wrote.[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66762/72988) is info.